Cube with one side curved
I am VERY new to Blender (and 3D modeling). I am trying to create a shape that looks like this from the top view (it is essentially a shelf):


I have tried to create the shape using a Cube, changing the dimensions of the box to align with the shelf that I would like to create and then use various Edge tools, but I am struggling.
Any help will be truly appreciated.
Thanks!

Hello could you please show a drawing of what you would like to be in 3D?

I have edited the original post with my best attempt in Gimp :)
.

Create a circle, scale down on Z:

Remove 3/4th of this circle, mirror with a Mirror modifier (enable the Clipping option):

Extrude this part and flatten (here flatten on X, SX0):

Extrude again (and flatten, here on Z, SZ0):

And again to give it thickness:

Bevel the edges:

Give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and Shade Smooth:


Wow! Thank you so very much!
I managed to get through the "Mirror" step, however during the first extrude step ("Extrude this part:") I am unable to get the outer edge to be straight. It is following the angle of the selected edge.
Forgive me, I am a genuine novice.

Oh yes I forgot to say that you need to flatten on the axis, in my case SZ0

Ughh. I am just not able to get it to work. I am having a problem with the flattening of the edges.
Thank you so much for your help and time, I think I will look into other alternatives.
Thanks again!

You need to press S to scale, then choose the axis on which you want to scale (X, Y or Z, depending on your object orientation), then 0.
